# Is it possible to limit the output length in ipython3

Tags: ipython

I perform some experiments on ipython3 and from time to time I display large list(e.g. about a million records) by mistake(e.g. by typing `p` where `p` has millions of records). As you can imagine I don't want to wait for the display to finish and what I do is hit ctrl+c. Unfortunately this terminates the ipython process instead of simply interrupting the output. This way I loose everything I've done so far and it takes significant time get again to the same point.

I know that for other interactive interpreters that it is possible to limit the output using some configuration to avoid such cases. Is there a similar option for ipython? Is there some alternative I can use in the case I describe above?